# Inside an equilateral triangle $ABC$,an arbitrary point $P$ is taken from which the perpendiculars $PD,PE$ and $PF$ are dropped onto the sides...

Tags: geometry

Inside an equilateral triangle $ABC$,an arbitrary point $P$ is taken from which the perpendiculars $PD,PE$ and $PF$ are dropped onto the sides $BC,CA$ and $AB$,respectively.Show that the ratio $\dfrac{PD+PE+PF}{BD+CE+AF}$ does not depend upon the choice of the point $P$ and find its value.

I have no idea how to proceed. I could not do anything beyond calculating the area of $PDB,PCE,PFA$ but here I get nothing. Please help!

Comment: Hint: $PD+PE+PF$ alone does not depend upon the choice of the point $P$. (Consider the areas of triangle $\triangle PBC$, $\triangle PCA$, $\triangle PAB$, and the sum thereof.)

Comment: I have calculated the sum after you said but could not find anything to proceed further. Please give me a little more hint.

Comment: Remember that the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: From that we can conclude that the sum is equal to $\frac12.$Product of Two sides.$\sin 60$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Very close. The point is that the sum is equal to the area of $\triangle ABC$; the trig representation of the area isn't as helpful as the $\frac{1}{2}\;\text{base}\cdot\text{height}$ representation.

Comment: But if I try to find the height...I will have to take the perpendicular...but in that case I would have to diverge from $P$.Will that be okay?

Comment: You don't really have to find the height, you just have to know it's there (and that it doesn't change); just call it $h$. And call the side-length $s$. Then notice that $s$ (and $h$) are used to compute the big triangle's area, while $s$ (and other things) are used to compute the sub-triangles' areas. Now what?

Comment: Now,$PD+PE+PF=h$.Can I extract more information from here?

Comment: Correct! This shows that $PD+PE+PF$ doesn't depend on $P$, which proves my hint. Now you just have to show that $BD+CE+AF$ alone doesn't depend on $P$. I don't have a hint for that. (I've never seen that fact before. I'm trying to prove it myself. :)

Comment: Can't we use Ceva or Menelaus Theorem for any help?

Comment: Is this alright? $\dfrac{BD}{DC} =\dfrac{\Delta ABD}{\Delta ADC}=\dfrac{\Delta PBD}{\Delta PDC}=\dfrac{\Delta APB}{\Delta APC}=\dfrac{AB}{AC}=1$.So,$BD=DC$?I think there is some problem

Comment: It's certainly not true that $BD=DC$ for every $P$. Ceva won't help, either, since lines $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ aren't necessarily concurrent. However, while I was away, (I think) I proved a useful alternative to Ceva's Theorem: *The perpendiculars at $D$, $E$, $F$ are concurrent (if and?) only if* $$AF^2 + BD^2 + CE^2 = FB^2 + DC^2 + EA^2$$ When I get more time, I'll write-up the proof in an answer.

Comment: Yes,I thought that was wrong...but it is according to Ceva, where is the mistake? Is there any restriction upon application of it?

Comment: To use Ceva's Theorem in that way would require that $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ meet at a point. This doesn't necessarily happen here.

Comment: Yes, Please post what you could derive and how...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a well-known fact (with proof sketched in the comments below the question) that
$$|PD|+|PE|+|PF| = \text{height of triangle}$$
so that the numerator of the target ratio is independent of $P$. It is perhaps less-well-known that 
$$|AF| + |BD| + |CE| = |FB| + |DC| + |EA| = \text{semi-perimeter of triangle} \qquad (\star)$$
which effectively solves the problem.

---

I was unaware of this second relation, so I set about proving it by (re-)deriving a Ceva-like theorem to characterize, not concurrent lines through a triangle's vertices (aka, "cevians"), but concurrent perpendiculars to a triangle's edges (aka ... um ... "orthians"? because they're orthogonal?); the theorem says this:

> **Ortha's Theorem.** Orthians at points $D$, $E$, $F$ on respective sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ of $\triangle ABC$ concur if and only if $$|AF|^2+|BD|^2+|CE|^2 = |FB|^2+|DC|^2+|EA|^2$$

Before proving this theorem, let's see how it shows $(\star)$.

Writing $s := |AB| = |BC| = |CA|$ in our equilateral triangle, we have
$$|FB| = s - |AF| \qquad |DC| = s - |BD| \qquad |EA| = s - |CE|$$
Since we know the orthians at $D$, $E$, $F$ meet at $P$, we can invoke the "only if" aspect of Ortha's Theorem to conclude
$$|AF|^2 + |BD|^2 + |CE|^2 = \left( s - |AF| \right)^2 + \left( s - |BD| \right)^2 + \left( s - |CE| \right)^2$$
whence
$$0 = s \left( 3 s - 2 \left( |AF| + |BD| + |CE| \right)\right)$$
so that (for non-zero $s$)
$$|AF|+|BD|+|CE| = \frac{3}{2}s = \text{semi-perimeter of } \triangle ABC$$

---

**Proof of Ortha's Theorem.** Orthians at points $E$ and $F$ definitely concur; call their common point $P$.

[image: Ortha's Theorem proof]

(Despite appearances in the image, $B$, $P$, and $E$ are not (necessarily) collinear; likewise $C$, $P$, $F$ ... or $A$, $P$, $D$, for that matter.)

Then ...

$$\begin{align}
PD \perp BC &\iff \quad |PB|^2 - |BD|^2 = |PC|^2 - |DC|^2 &(1) \\[6pt]
&\iff |PF|^2 + |FB|^2 - |BD|^2 = |PE|^2 + |CE|^2 - |DC|^2 \\
&\iff |PA|^2 - |AF|^2 + |FB|^2 - |BD|^2 = |PA|^2 - |EA|^2 + |CE|^2 - |DC|^2 \\[6pt]
&\iff |AF|^2 +|BD|^2 + |CE|^2 = |FB|^2 + |DC|^2 + |EA|^2 &\square
\end{align}$$

(In $(1)$, the "$\Rightarrow$" part is clear, as each side of the equation gives $|PD|^2$. The "$\Leftarrow$" part follows from slightly more effort, which is left to the reader. Note that only the "$\Rightarrow$" part needed to show $(\star)$.)

---

I suspect this theorem must be known in the literature. (Of course, I invented the name "Ortha" as a back-construction of my invented word "orthian", to mimic the connection between "Ceva" and "cevian".) Come to think of it, the result here is equivalent to equation $(\star\star\star)$ in [this answer of mine from a few months ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/547319/409) that generalizes Ceva's theorem to arbitrary lines meeting a triangle. So, I guess my suspicion is that this theorem must be known *somewhere else* in the literature.

Comment: This proof was truly great...thanks a ton!! I was banging my head on the wall for a solution to this question...I kept on thinking but could not find a solution...You did a really great job!!

Comment: What I call "Ortha's Theorem" is officially known as [Carnot's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Carnot.shtml) (not to be confused with [Carnot's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/carnot.shtml)).

Comment: @blue when it was not clicking to u how to make BD+CE+AF a constant how u got an idea of ortha theorem, like can u tell please how go further in a problem when u are stuck?

Answer (score 10):

For simplicity, let the sides of the triangle be $1$.

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

Looking at the areas of the sub-triangles, we get
$$
\begin{align}
|\,\triangle ABP\,|&=\frac12|\,\overline{FP}\,|\times|\,\overline{AB}\,|=\frac12|\,\overline{FP}\,|\\
|\,\triangle BCP\,|&=\frac12|\,\overline{DP}\,|\times|\,\overline{BC}\,|=\frac12|\,\overline{DP}\,|\tag{1}\\
|\,\triangle CAP\,|&=\frac12|\,\overline{EP}\,|\times|\,\overline{CA}\,|=\frac12|\,\overline{EP}\,|
\end{align}
$$
Summing these, we get
$$
|\,\overline{FP}\,|+|\,\overline{DP}\,|+|\,\overline{EP}\,|=2|\,\triangle ABC\,|=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\tag{2}
$$

---

Rename the distances in question as $x$, $y$, and $z$.

$\hspace{2.3cm}$[image]

Considering the vertical distances on sides $x$ and $y$ and then repeating the same for the other side pairs:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x+\frac12h_x&=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}(1-y)+\frac12h_y\\
\frac{\sqrt3}{2}y+\frac12h_y&=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}(1-z)+\frac12h_z\tag{3}\\
\frac{\sqrt3}{2}z+\frac12h_z&=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}(1-x)+\frac12h_x
\end{align}
$$
Adding these and cancelling results in
$$
x+y+z=\frac32\tag{4}
$$
That is
$$
|\,\overline{FA}\,|+|\,\overline{DB}\,|+|\,\overline{EC}\,|=\frac32\tag{5}
$$

---

Thus, $(2)$ and $(5)$ yield
$$
\frac{|\,\overline{FP}\,|+|\,\overline{DP}\,|+|\,\overline{EP}\,|}{|\,\overline{FA}\,|+|\,\overline{DB}\,|+|\,\overline{EC}\,|}=\frac1{\sqrt3}\tag{6}
$$

Comment: Very good solution...thank you!