# Proving $HH', BB', CC'$ are concurrent?

Tags: geometry, triangles

The orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$ is $H$. Let $B'$ be a point on AC and $C'$ be a point on AB, such that $BCB'C'$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Let the orthocenter of $\triangle AB'C'$ be $H'$.

> Prove that the lines $BB', CC'$and $HH'$ are concurrent.

[image]

I am quite lost on how to solve the question. I know that $\triangle AB'C'$ is similar to $\triangle ABC$, but how may I use this to advantage? Can anyone help? :)

Comment: This is part of a well-known theorem: Given four points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ on a circle, we can define $X = AB \cap CD$ and $Y = BC \cap DA$, and consider the orthocenters of the triangles $XBC$, $XDA$, $YCD$ and $YAB$. Then, these four orthocenters lie on one line, which also passes through $AC \cap BD$. If I remember correctly, there is a way to prove this using Steiner lines, but probably more directly too.

Comment: Actually, here is the probably nicest proof: If we drop the condition that the four points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ lie on one circle, then it is a well-known fact that the circles with diameters $AC$, $BD$ and $XY$ are coaxial, and the orthocenters of the triangles $XBC$, $XDA$, $YCD$ and $YAB$ lie on their (common) radical axis. It thus only remains to show that if $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ lie on a circle, then $AC \cap BD$ also lies on this radical axis. Indeed, ...

Comment: ... if we denote $AC \cap BD$ by $Z$, then $ZA \cdot ZC = ZB \cdot ZD$ (with directed segments) shows that $Z$ lies on the radical axis of the circles with diameters $AC$ and $BD$, and we are done.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for them, I hope you can write them into answers. But I don't what do we mean by circles are coaxial? :/

Comment: Three circles are said to be coaxial if their pairwise radical axes coincide. Or maybe "coaxal"; I never remember the right spelling. Either way, the theorem I quoted, or at least part of it, is the Gauss-Bodenmiller theorem: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/CircleOnCevian.shtml#GB .

Comment: @darijgrinberg, nice. this looks like a theorem in projective geometry something to with harmonic quadrangles. does this have a name?

Comment: You don't need anything harmonic here. I am typing up a complete proof right now.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Hi Darij, nice to meet you again. I think I beat you up with a "trilinear brutality" proof :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete proof along the lines of my comments to the OP. Most of it
is well-known stuff, but it probably doesn't hurt to build it from scratch.

First of all, the problem follows from the following claim:

**Theorem 1.** Let $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ be four points on a circle. Let
$X=AB\cap CD$ and $Y=BC\cap DA$. (I use the notation $\ell\cap m$ to denote
the point of intersection of two lines $\ell$ and $m$, even though it would be
more formally correct to say that $\ell\cap m$ is a one-element set consisting
of this point. I also pretend that everything is in general position when
needed, as usually done in this kind of geometry.) Then, the orthocenters of
the triangles $XBC$, $XDA$, $YAB$ and $YCD$ lie on one line, and the point
$AC\cap BD$ also lies on this line.

To recover the original problem from this theorem, we need to apply it to $C$,
$B^{\prime}$, $C^{\prime}$, $B$ and $A$ instead of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $X$.

Theorem 1 is not the pinnacle of generality. Indeed, there is a more
well-known fact which generalizes it:

**Theorem 2.** Let $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ be four points on the plane. Let
$X=AB\cap CD$ and $Y=BC\cap DA$. Then:

**(a)** The midpoints of the segments $AC$, $BD$ and $XY$ lie on one line.

**(b)** The circles with diameters $AC$, $BD$ and $XY$ are coaxal (i.e.,
their pairwise radical axes coincide).

**(c)** The orthocenters of the triangles $XBC$, $XDA$, $YAB$ and $YCD$
all lie on the radical axis of any two of the circles with diameters $AC$,
$BD$ and $XY$.

**(d)** If the points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ lie on one circle, then the
point $AC\cap BD$ also lies on this radical axis.

It is clear that parts **(c)** and **(d)** of Theorem 2, when
combined, yield Theorem 1. It therefore only remains to prove Theorem 2.

Part of Theorem 2 (I am not sure which part) is called the Gauss-Bodenmiller
theorem. Also, the line constructed in Theorem 2 **(a)** is known as the
Gauss-Newton line of the complete quadrilateral formed by the lines $AB$,
$BC$, $CD$ and $DA$. The radical axis in Theorem 2 **(c)** is known as the
Miquel-Steiner line of this complete quadrilateral.
Notice that Theorem 2 **(a)** is a purely affine
statement (i.e., it involves only constructions invariant under affine
transformations, such as midpoints of segments and intersections of lines),
but we will prove it as a side effect of an argument that involves circles.

*Proof of Theorem 2.* We introduce the notation $\operatorname*{Thal}
\left(  PQ\right)  $ for the circle with diameter $PQ$, where $P$ and $Q$ are
any two points. We also define $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  k,k^{\prime
}\right)  $ to be the radical axis of two circles $k$ and $k^{\prime}$.
Finally, we let $H_{PQR}$ denote the orthocenter of any triangle $PQR$.

We notice that the orthocenters $H_{XBC}$, $H_{XDA}$, $H_{YAB}$ and $H_{YCD}$
are pairwise distinct when $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are in general position. This
allows us to WLOG assume that these four orthocenters are distinct; we will
use this assumption below.

Let us begin by proving that $H_{XBC}\in\operatorname*{Rad}\left(
\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)
\right)  $. Indeed, let $B^{\prime}$ be the foot of the altitude of triangle
$XBC$ emanating from $B$. Then, $H_{XBC}\in BB^{\prime}$, so that $BB^{\prime
}=BH_{XBC}$. Also, $BB^{\prime}\perp XC$ (since $B^{\prime}$ is the foot of
the altitude from $B$ to $XC$), and thus $\measuredangle BB^{\prime
}D=90^{\circ}$, so that $B^{\prime}\in\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)
$. Also, $BB^{\prime}\perp XC$ yields $\measuredangle BB^{\prime}C=90^{\circ}
$, so that $B^{\prime}\in\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BC\right)  $. From
$B^{\prime}\in\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BC\right)  $ and $B^{\prime}
\in\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  $, we see that the circles
$\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BC\right)  $ and $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
BD\right)  $ have the point $B^{\prime}$ in common. Since they also have the
point $B$ in common, this shows that the circles $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
BC\right)  $ and $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  $ intersect at the
two points $B$ and $B^{\prime}$ (here we WLOG assume that $B$ and $B^{\prime}$
are distinct, which is another consequence of general position). Thus, the
radical axis of these circles is $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(
\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)
\right)  =BB^{\prime}=BH_{XBC}$.

The same argument (but applied to $D$, $C$, $B$ and $A$ instead of $A$, $B$,
$C$ and $D$) shows that $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}
\left(  CB\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  CA\right)  \right)  =CH_{XCB}
$. Since $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  CB\right)  =\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
BC\right)  $, $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  CA\right)  =\operatorname*{Thal}
\left(  AC\right)  $ and $H_{XCB}=H_{XBC}$, this rewrites as
$\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BC\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  \right)  =CH_{XBC}$.

Now, the point $H_{XBC}$ lies on both lines $BH_{XBC}=\operatorname*{Rad}
\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
BD\right)  \right)  $ and $CH_{XBC}=\operatorname*{Rad}\left(
\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)
\right)  $, and these two lines are distinct (since $BH_{XBC}\neq CH_{XBC}$ in
general position). Thus, $H_{XBC}$ lies on two of the three pairwise mutual
radical axes of the three circles $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BC\right)  $,
$\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  $ and $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  $. Consequently, $H_{XBC}$ must be the radical center of these
three circles, and so must lie on the third radical axis as well. In other words,

**(1)** $H_{XBC}\in\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $.

The same argument (applied to $B$, $C$, $D$, $A$, $Y$ and $X$ instead of $A$,
$B$, $C$, $D$, $X$ and $Y$) shows that

**(2)** $H_{YCD}\in\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(
BD\right)  ,\underbrace{\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  CA\right)  }
_{=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  }\right)  =\operatorname*{Rad}
\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  \right)  =\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $.

Also, **(1)** (applied to $C$, $D$, $A$ and $B$ instead of $A$, $B$, $C$ and
$D$) shows that

**(3)** $H_{XDA}\in\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \underbrace{\operatorname*{Thal}
\left(  CA\right)  }_{=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  }
,\underbrace{\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  DB\right)  }_{=\operatorname*{Thal}
\left(  BD\right)  }\right)  =\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}
\left(  AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $.

Finally, **(1)** (applied to $D$, $A$, $B$, $C$, $Y$ and $X$ instead of $A$,
$B$, $C$, $D$, $X$ and $Y$) shows that

**(4)** $H_{YAB}\in\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \underbrace{\operatorname*{Thal}
\left(  DB\right)  }_{=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  }
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  \right)  =\operatorname*{Rad}\left(
\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)
\right)  =\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $.

Combining the relations **(1)**, **(2)**, **(3)** and **(4)**, we conclude
that the orthocenters $H_{XBC}$, $H_{XDA}$, $H_{YAB}$ and $H_{YCD}$ all lie on
the line $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $. Thus,

**(5)** $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $ is the line through the
four points $H_{XBC}$, $H_{XDA}$, $H_{YAB}$ and $H_{YCD}$.

(Here, we use our WLOG assumption that these four points are distinct!)
Applying **(5)** to $X$, $C$, $Y$, $A$, $D$ and $B$ instead of $A$, $B$, $C$,
$D$, $X$ and $Y$, we obtain:

$\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  XY\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  CA\right)  \right)  $ is the line through the
four points $H_{DCY}$, $H_{DAX}$, $H_{BXC}$ and $H_{BYA}$.

Since $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  CA\right)  =\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  $, $H_{DCY}=H_{YCD}$, $H_{DAX}=H_{XDA}$, $H_{BXC}=H_{XBC}$ and
$H_{BYA}=H_{YAB}$, this rewrites as follows:

$\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  XY\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  \right)  $ is the line through the
four points $H_{YCD}$, $H_{XDA}$, $H_{XBC}$ and $H_{YAB}$.

In other words,

$\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  XY\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  \right)  $ is the line through the
four points $H_{XBC}$, $H_{XDA}$, $H_{YAB}$ and $H_{YCD}$.

Compared with **(5)**, this yields that $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(
\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  XY\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)
\right)  =\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $.

Now, recall that if three circles $k$, $k^{\prime}$ and $k^{\prime\prime}$
satisfy $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  k,k^{\prime}\right)  =\operatorname*{Rad}
\left(  k^{\prime},k^{\prime\prime}\right)  $, then these three circles are
coaxal. Applying this to $k=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  XY\right)  $,
$k^{\prime}=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  $ and $k^{\prime\prime
}=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  $, we conclude that the circles
$\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  XY\right)  $, $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  $ and $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  $ are coaxal. In
other words, the circles $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  $,
$\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  $ and $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
XY\right)  $ are coaxal. In other words, the circles with diameters $AC$, $BD$
and $XY$ are coaxal. This proves Theorem 2 **(b)**.

If three circles are coaxal, then their centers lie on one line. Thus, the
centers of the circles with diameters $AC$, $BD$ and $XY$ lie on one line
(since we know that these circles are coaxal). In other words, the midpoints
of the segments $AC$, $BD$ and $XY$ lie on one line (because for any $P$ and
$Q$, the center of the circle with diameter $PQ$ is the midpoint of the
segment $PQ$). This proves Theorem 2 **(a)**.

Now let us prove Theorem 2 **(c)**. We need to prove that the
orthocenters of the triangles $XBC$, $XDA$, $YAB$ and $YCD$ (that is, the four
points $H_{XBC}$, $H_{XDA}$, $H_{YAB}$ and $H_{YCD}$) all lie on the radical
axis of any two of the circles with diameters $AC$, $BD$ and $XY$. Since we
already know that these orthocenters all lie on the line $\operatorname*{Rad}
\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
BD\right)  \right)  $, it suffices to show that the line $\operatorname*{Rad}
\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
BD\right)  \right)  $ is the radical axis of any two of the circles with
diameters $AC$, $BD$ and $XY$. In other words, it suffices to show that the
line $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)
,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $ is the radical axis of any
two of the circles $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  $,
$\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  $ and $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
XY\right)  $. But this follows from the fact that if $k$, $k^{\prime}$ and
$k^{\prime\prime}$ are three coaxal circles, then $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(
k,k^{\prime}\right)  $ is the radical axis of any two of the circles $k$,
$k^{\prime}$ and $k^{\prime\prime}$. (We apply this fact to
$k=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  $, $k^{\prime}=\operatorname*{Thal}
\left(  BD\right)  $ and $k^{\prime\prime}=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
XY\right)  $ here). Theorem 2 **(c)** is thus proven.

**(d)** Finally, let us prove Theorem 2 **(d)**. We already know
that the line $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $ is the radical
axis of any two of the circles with diameters $AC$, $BD$ and $XY$. Hence, in
order to prove Theorem 2 **(d)**, it is enough to show that, if the
points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ lie on one circle, then the point $AC\cap BD$
lies on the line $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $. So let us
assume that the points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ lie on one circle. Let $\kappa$
denote this circle. Let $Z=AC\cap BD$. Then, the two chords $AC$ and $BD$ of
$\kappa$ intersect at $Z$. Thus, $ZA\cdot ZC=ZB\cdot ZD$ (according to the
intersecting chords theorem), where the segments are directed.

But if $P$ is a point and $k$ is a circle, and if a line through $P$
intersects $k$ at two points $U$ and $V$, then the power of $P$ with respect
to the circle $k$ is $PU\cdot PV$ (with directed segments). Applying this to
$P=Z$, $k=\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  $, $U=A$ and $V=C$, we see
that the power of $Z$ with respect to the circle $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  $ is $ZA\cdot ZC$. Similarly, the power of $Z$ with respect to the
circle $\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  $ is $ZB\cdot ZD$. These two
powers are thus equal (since $ZA\cdot ZC=ZB\cdot ZD$), and therefore $Z$ lies
on the radical axis $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(  \operatorname*{Thal}\left(
AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)  \right)  $. In other words,
the point $AC\cap BD$ lies on the radical axis $\operatorname*{Rad}\left(
\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  AC\right)  ,\operatorname*{Thal}\left(  BD\right)
\right)  $ (since $Z=AC\cap BD$). This completes the proof of Theorem 2
**(d)**.

Nothing in the above proofs depends on the configuration of the points, as
long as it is generic enough; but I wouldn't mind if someone would make a
picture nevertheless :)

**EDIT:** See also https://problemsolversparadise.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/on-the-complete-quadrilateral-configurations/ .

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using multiple applications of an Extended Ceva's Theorem that [I introduced in a previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/547319/409). The theorem gives a condition for concurrence of (almost) any three lines passing through the edges of a triangle, not just those through vertices.

> **Extended Ceva's Theorem.** Consider points $D_1$, $D_2$, $E_1$, $E_2$, $F_1$, $F_2$ on the (extended) edges of $\triangle ABC$, with each $D_i$, $E_i$, $F_i$ on the (extended) edge opposite vertex $A$, $B$, $C$, respectively.
>
> [image]
>
> Lines $\overleftrightarrow{D_1E_2}$, $\overleftrightarrow{E_1F_2}$, $\overleftrightarrow{F_1D_2}$ concur if and only if
>   $$\begin{align}
> 1 &= \frac{|BD_1|}{|D_1C|} \frac{|CE_1|}{|E_1A|} \frac{|AF_1|}{|F_1B|} 
> + \frac{|D_2C|}{|BD_2|} \frac{|E_2A|}{|CE_2|} \frac{|F_2B|}{|AF_2|} \\[6pt]
> &+ \frac{|BD_1|}{|D_1C|} \frac{|D_2C|}{|BD_2|}
> + \frac{|CE_1|}{|E_1A|} \frac{|E_2A|}{|CE_2|}
> + \frac{|AF_1|}{|F_1B|} \frac{|F_2B|}{|AF_2|} \qquad (\star)
> \end{align}$$

In the current scenario, we could take our lines to be $\overleftrightarrow{BB^\prime}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CC^\prime}$, and $\overleftrightarrow{HH^\prime}$. The last of these we would need to extend to give points, say $D$ on $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ and $E$ on $\overleftrightarrow{CA}$.

[image]

The corresponding concurrence condition arises from the substitutions
$$F_2 \to B, \quad E_1 \to B^\prime, \quad D_2 \to C, \quad F_1 \to C^\prime, \quad D_1 \to D, \quad E_2 \to E$$
which reduce $(\star)$ to 
$$\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{|CB^\prime|}{|B^\prime A|}\;\left(\; \frac{|BD|}{|DC|} \frac{|AC^\prime|}{|C^\prime B|} + \frac{|EA|}{|CE|}\;\right) \qquad (1)
\end{align}$$

As OP notes, $\triangle AB^\prime C^\prime \sim \triangle ACB$, say with proportionality factor $k$. This makes computing two of the ratios easy:

$$\frac{|CB^\prime|}{|B^\prime A|} = \frac{b - k c }{k c} \qquad\qquad 
\frac{|AC^\prime|}{|C^\prime B|} = \frac{k b}{c-k b}$$

The remaining two ratios, which we'll name
$$ m := \frac{|BD|}{|DC|} \qquad\qquad n := \frac{|EA|}{|CE|}$$
are a *little* trickier to deduce. One can use coordinates, but for less effort than  it takes to determine points $D$ and $E$ from $\overleftrightarrow{HH^\prime}$ and calculate the ratios, you could just verify that the intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{BB^\prime}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{CC^\prime}$ lies on $\overleftrightarrow{HH^\prime}$. There may also be a clever geometric argument leveraging various similar triangles, but I want to try something different.

Instead, we'll take advantage of the fact that each of $H$ and $H^\prime$ is a point of concurrence of $\overleftrightarrow{HH^\prime}$ with two other lines. This gives us two instances of $(\star)$ involving $m$ and $n$, so that we can *solve for* these values.

First, $H$ is where $\overleftrightarrow{HH^\prime}$ meets $\overleftrightarrow{BP}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{CQ}$. The Extended Ceva's Theorem with the substitutions
$$F_2 \to B, \quad E_1 \to P, \quad D_2 \to C, \quad F_1 \to Q, \quad D_1 \to D, \quad E_2 \to E$$
gives
$$1 = \frac{|CP|}{|PA|}\;\left(\; m \; \frac{|AQ|}{|QB|} + n\;\right)$$
so that 
$$1 = \frac{a\cos C}{c\cos A}\;\left(\; m \; \frac{b \cos A}{a \cos B} + n\;\right) = m \; \frac{b \cos C}{c\cos B} + n\;\frac{a \cos C}{c \cos A} \qquad(2)$$

On the other hand, $H^\prime$ is the point where $\overleftrightarrow{HH^\prime}$ meets $\overleftrightarrow{B^\prime P^\prime}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{C^\prime Q^\prime}$. Unfortunately, we can't just make substitutions into $(\star)$ using $B^\prime$, $C^\prime$, $P^\prime$, $Q^\prime$, $D$, $E$, since these points aren't in the appropriate configuration on the edges of $\triangle ABC$. To remedy this, take $X = \overleftrightarrow{BC}\cap\overleftrightarrow{B^\prime P^\prime}$ ; then we can make these substitutions:
$$D_2 \to X, \quad F_1 \to P^\prime, \quad F_2 \to C^\prime, \quad E_1 \to Q^\prime, \quad D_1 \to D, \quad E_2 \to E$$
to get 
$$\begin{align}
1 &= m\; \frac{|CQ^\prime|}{|Q^\prime A|} \frac{|AP^\prime|}{|P^\prime B|} 
+ n \; \frac{|XC|}{|BX|} \frac{|C^\prime B|}{|AC^\prime|} \\[6pt]
&+ m\; \frac{|XC|}{|BX|}
+ n \; \frac{|CQ^\prime|}{|Q^\prime A|}
+ \frac{|AP^\prime|}{|P^\prime B|} \frac{|C^\prime B|}{|AC^\prime|}
\end{align}$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
1 &= m\; \frac{b-kb\cos A}{k b \cos A} \frac{k c \cos A}{c - k c \cos A} 
- n \; \frac{(c-kc\cos A)/\cos B - a}{(c-kc\cos A)/\cos B} \frac{c - k b}{k b} \\[6pt]
&- m\; \frac{(c-kc\cos A)/\cos B - a}{(c-kc\cos A)/\cos B}
+ n \; \frac{b - k b \cos A}{k b \cos A}
+ \frac{k c \cos A}{c - k c \cos A} \frac{c - k b}{k b}
\end{align}$$

(Note the sign change with the $|XC|/|BX|$ terms, since $\overrightarrow{XC}$ and $\overrightarrow{BX}$ point in opposite directions.) This becomes

$$ k c \cos A \cos C = m\;k b \cos A\cos B
+ n \; ( c \sin A \sin B - k \cos A ( c \cos C + b \cos B )) \quad (3)$$

Solving $(2)$ and $(3)$ for $m$ and $n$ gives
$$
m = \frac{(c - k b ) \cos B}{(b - k c ) \cos C} \qquad\qquad
n = \frac{k (b^2-c^2) \cos A}{a ( b - k c )\cos C}
$$
and one can verify that these satisfy $(1)$, proving the concurrence of $\overleftrightarrow{BB^\prime}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CC^\prime}$, $\overleftrightarrow{HH^\prime}$. $\square$

Admittedly, the algebraic details got a bit hairier than I intended when I embarked on this journey. (The reader is invited to derive $m$ and $n$ via clever geometry, so as to use $(1)$ more-directly.) Nevertheless, I think this makes for a not-unreasonable application of the Extended Ceva Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so difficult to prove such concurrency with trilinear coordinates.

Let $A=[1,0,0],B=[0,1,0],C=[0,0,1],H=\left[\frac{1}{\cos A},\frac{1}{\cos B}.\frac{1}{\cos C}\right]$.

In order to have $BCB'C'$ cyclic, we must have $\frac{AC'}{AB'}=\frac{AC}{AB}$, so:
$$ B'=[b-\lambda c,0,\lambda a],\qquad C'=[c-\lambda b,\lambda a,0],$$
and the coordinates of the lines $BB',CC'$ in the dual space are:
$$ BB'^*=[\lambda a,0,\lambda c-b],\quad CC'^*=[\lambda a,\lambda b-c,0],$$
and:
$$ X = BB'\cap CC' = \left[1,\frac{\lambda a}{c-\lambda b},\frac{\lambda a}{b-\lambda c}\right].$$
So, we have just to compute the trilinear coordinates of $H'$ and check that $X\in HH'.$

We have $d\left(H',AB\right)=\frac{1}{\lambda}d(H,AC), d\left(H',AC\right)=\frac{1}{\lambda}d(H,AB)$, so:
$$ H'=\left[\cdot,\frac{1}{\lambda\cos C},\frac{1}{\lambda\cos B}\right]=\left[\star,\cos B,\cos C\right],$$
giving that the circumcenter of $ABC$ belongs to the $AH'$ line. At last, we have just to compute $d(H',BC)$ in order to find $\star$ and check that $X\in HH'$. This is left to the reader since it is not so interesting, I think that the interesting part of this answer is the shown technique.