# Trisecting the sides of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Consider the hexagon formed by the six points which trisect the sides of a triangle(two on each side).  *Is is true that when we connect opposite points in this hexagon, the lines intersect at a single point ?*  I think this is most likely true but I cant prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they do meet at the center of the triangle. to see this let we $a, b, c$ represent the points. call the points $A_1, A_2$ on $BC$ such that $BA_1 = A_1A_2 = A_2C$ the point $a_1 = 2/3 b + 1/3 c, a_2=1/3b + 2/3 c$ similarly define points $b_1=1/3 c+2/3a, b_2 = 2/3 c+ 1/3 a.$  the point where all diameters meet is mid point of $A_1B_1$ given by $(a+b+c)/3.$

Comment: How did you know that the point where all the diameters meet is the midpoint?

Comment: the line $B_1A_1$ is parallel to $B_2A_2$ and $B_1A_1 = 2B_2A_2$

Comment: ohh I see. Thanks!

Comment: Will they meet at centroid??

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, yes, they do meet at the centroid.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the diagonals meet at a common point.

[image]

Certainly, the diagonals are parallel to, and two-thirds the length of, corresponding sides of the triangle. Consider a sub-triangle (say, $\triangle AF_2 E_1$) created by one of the diagonals and an appropriate vertex. The other diagonals ($F_1D_2$ and $E_2 D_1$) are parallel to sides ($AF_2$ and $AE_1$) of that triangle at the corresponding midpoints; those diagonals, then, necessarily meet the midpoint ($M$) of the remaining side (namely, diagonal $F_2 E_1$) at their own midpoints. $\square$

---

Alternatively (though less-enlighteningly), you could use my Extended Ceva's Theorem from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/547319/409), which gives this condition for concurrence:

> $$\begin{align}
> 1 &
> = \frac{|BD_1|}{|D_1C|}\;\frac{|CE_1|}{|E_1A|}\;\frac{|AF_1|}{|F_1B|} + \frac{|D_2C|}{|BD_2|}\;\frac{|E_2A|}{|CE_2|}\;\frac{|F_2B|}{|AF_2|} \\[4pt]
> &+\frac{|BD_1|}{|D_1C|}\;\frac{|D_2C|}{|BD_2|}+\frac{|CE_1|}{|E_1A|}\;\frac{|E_2A|}{|CE_2|}+\frac{|AF_1|}{|F_1B|}\;\frac{|F_2B|}{|AF_2|}
> \end{align}$$

In this situation, all ratios are $\frac12$, so the condition is satisfied and the lines are concurrent. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

Not too hard, borrowing the diagram above.
Easy to prove triangles F1E2M and D2D1M are congruent (using similar triangles to first show F1E2||BC and F1E2=BC/3=D1D2).
Thus E2M=D1M and F1M=D2M.
M is the midpoint of F1D2 and E2D1.
Join F2 and M.
Triangles F1F2M and F1BD2 must be similar (two sides in same ratio and included angle)
Using corresponding angles, F2M||BC.
The same way we can show E1M||BC
F2ME1 must be a straight line, so concurrency is proved.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).