# Prove that the lines parallel to the angle bisectors through the midpoints of sides of a triangle are concurrent at the Spieker center

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I've been learning about triangle centers, and I have been able to prove that most of them exist. However, this one that I've come across has stumped a bit, and I haven't been able to find any proofs or hints towards how to prove this specific point always exists. I believe the point is called the Spieker center. The problem prompt goes a little like this.

> Given a triangle $ABC$, construct lines parallel to the interior angle bisectors of angles $A$, $B$, and $C$, such that they pass through the midpoints of sides $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ respectively. Prove that these lines are concurrent.

Any ideas on how I should approach this proof?

Comment: To confirm: This is indeed called the [Spieker center](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpiekerCenter.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concurrency is evident using the medial triangle property as stated in the answer by cosmo5. Here is wiki link that you can refer to for more on it ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_triangle)).

Here is a more elementary proof simply using, i) the midpoint theorem, ii) alternate interior angles theorem which states that if two parallel lines are cut by a traversal, the alternate interior angles are congruent, and iii) Concurrency of angle bisectors theorem.

[image]

$D, E$ and $F$ are midpoints of the sides of $\triangle ABC$. Line through $AM$ is the angle bisector of $\angle A$. Line through $EN$ is parallel to $AM$ and through midpoint $E$ of side $BC$.

Using midpoint theorem, $ADEF$ is a parallelogram and $\angle DEF = \angle A$.

Using property of parallel lines, $\angle FEN = \angle FMA = \angle MAD = \frac{\angle A}{2}$. So line through $EN$ is angle bisector of $\angle DEF$ in $\triangle DEF$. By the same logic, parallel lines through midpoints to other two angle bisectors of $\triangle ABC$ must be angle bisectors of $\angle DFE$ and $\angle EDF$.

Hence the proof is complete by concurrency of angle bisectors of a triangle.

Answer (score 5):

Rotate the original triangle $ABC$ by $180^\circ$ about its centroid $G$ and scale down to half its size. It will coincide with the triangle formed by its midpoints $D,E,F$.

The angle bisectors of $ABC$ would go to angle bisectors of $DEF$. Since any line rotated by $180^\circ$, a half turn, remains parallel to itself, the angle bisectors of $DEF$ are the lines to be constructed in the question.

We know that angle bisectors of any triangle concur at a single point, namely its incenter. Hence the lines through midpoints and parallel to the angle bisectors of $ABC$ concur at the incenter of $DEF$. The incenter of $DEF$ is simply the image of incenter of $ABC$ under our transformation (a half turn about centroid followed by scaling by half). The proof is complete.

Comment: +1. I got so caught-up in the bisector-parallels generalization that I looked right past the obvious "the Spieker center is the incenter of the medial triangle" approach for this specific case. :) ... Well, perhaps OP will still find the Extended Ceva Theorem helpful in exploring more circle centers.

Comment: @Blue But your answer and the links therein were quite useful. Thankyou for writing those previous answers! :)

Comment: It's worth noting that angle-bisector-ness, *per se*, isn't required for this argument. The rotate-and-scale transformation guarantees that *any* trio of cevians through $A$, $B$, $C$ transfers to correspondingly-arranged parallel cevians through $D$, $E$, $F$; and, thus, the first trio's point of concurrence (if it exists, which it does in the case of the angle bisectors) transfers to the second's.

Comment: That is very nice! So we have two-sided correspondence : parallel lines through $A,D \iff $ corresponding cevians.

Answer (score 2):

I'll exploit a result that I presented [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/547319/409), with different notation:

[image]

> **Extended Ceva's Theorem.** Defining ratios of *signed lengths*,
> $$\alpha^+ := \frac{|BA^+|}{|A^+C|} \qquad \beta^+ :=\frac{|CB^+|}{|B^+A|} \qquad \gamma^+ := \frac{|AC^+|}{|C^+B|}$$
> $$\alpha^- := \frac{|CA^-|}{|A^-B|} \qquad \beta^- :=\frac{|AB^-|}{|B^-C|} \qquad \gamma^- := \frac{|BC^-|}{|C^-A|}$$
> the lines $\overleftrightarrow{A^+B^-}$, $\overleftrightarrow{B^+C^-}$, $\overleftrightarrow{C^+A^-}$ concur iff
> $$\alpha^+\beta^+\gamma^+ + \alpha^-\beta^-\gamma^- + \alpha^+\alpha^- + \beta^+\beta^- + \gamma^+\gamma^- \;=\; 1\tag{$\star$} $$

If $A^+$, $B^+$, $C^+$ are midpoints, then $\alpha^+=\beta^+=\gamma^+=1$, and $(\star)$ reduces to
$$\alpha^-\beta^-\gamma^- + \alpha^-+\beta^-+\gamma^- = 0$$
However, we'll find that the angle bisector context makes it natural to express the "$-$" ratios in terms of the "$+$" ones; so I won't invoke the midpoint property prematurely.

---

Focusing on the angle bisector from $A$ aspect, let $\overleftrightarrow{A^+B^-}$ be parallel to that bisector, and let it meet the extended side $\overline{AB}$ at $V$.

[image]

With $u$, $v$, $\theta$ as labeled in the figure, we can use the Law of Sines on $\triangle BA^+V$ and $\triangle CA^+B^-$ to write
$$\frac{\alpha^+ u}{c+v} = \frac{\sin\frac12A}{\sin\theta} = \frac{u}{b-v} \quad\to\quad v = \frac{\alpha^+b-c}{\alpha^++1} \quad\to\quad
\beta^-:=\frac{v}{b-v}=\frac{\alpha^+ b-c}{b+c}$$
Likewise,
$$\gamma^-=\frac{\beta^+ c-a}{c+a} \qquad \alpha^-=\frac{\gamma^+ a-b}{a+b}$$

Substituting into $(\star)$, we can write
$$\frac{(1 + \alpha^+)(1 - \beta^+ \gamma^+)}{a}
+ \frac{(1 + \beta^+ )(1 - \gamma^+\alpha^+)}{b}
+ \frac{(1 + \gamma^+)(1 - \alpha^+\beta^+ )}{c} = 0\tag{$\star\star$}$$
This general condition for concurrence of bisector-parallels through $A^+$, $B^+$, $C^+$ is clearly satisfied when $\alpha^+=\beta^+=\gamma^+=1$ (ie, when $A^+$, $B^+$, $C^+$ are midpoints). $\square$